# Https not working on AWS EC2 with ssl certificate installed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I Have insatlled ssl on my aws but not able to load my site on https https://darkcloud.app (My site)
[Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bdhu.png)
[load balancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMiuw.png)
[Route 53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILInp.png)

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-134:~$ curl -v https://www.darkcloud.app
Rebuilt URL to: https://www.darkcloud.app/
  Trying 54.153.123.21...
Connected to www.darkcloud.app (54.153.123.21) port 443 (#0)
found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
found 594 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
ALPN, offering http/1.1
gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Closing connection 0
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
```

Comment: Can you post the Apache configs you're using? Also, mention Apache 2.4.18 and Ubuntu server (which I gathered from looking at the response headers). And mention the URL is "www.darkcloud.app" if it really is, which it seems to be. Plus... put the output of `curl -v https://www.darkcloud.app` in your question

Comment: Edited question

Comment: We need your Apache config file. Basically, it looks like you haven't configured Apache for SSL, even though it is listening on port 443

Comment: Here it is http://54.153.123.21/apache2.conf

Comment: So, what is in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled` and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` - those two directories should have configs in them for your site. Also, possibly, `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` - I think it would be easier for you to just google `Configure SSL on Apache tutorial`

Comment: @AnandChandwani you have configured load balancer with SSL but the DNS record is pointing to the individual instance, you need to setup dns `CNAME` record to point to the load balancer's dns name, this way you will have SSL terminated at load balancer and apache on the backend server will receive non-ssl traffic, so no need to change anything on apache level

Comment: How can i do that deepak ? can you help me that ?

Comment: Anand, I think it might be best to do a bunch of googling and look at tutorials. This is a site I looked at when I was first starting: https://www.howtoforge.com/

Comment: Thanks my site is working but getting  some error https://darkcloud.app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be multiple issues:

1. You are accessing the site with `darkcloud.app` but it doesn't have a DNS entry, create a similar DNS entry as `www.darkcloud.app` in route53
2. Accessing site on port 443 i.e. https gives "unknown protocol" error that shows that load balancer is not configured properly for https, see curl output below:

   $ curl -I https://www.darkcloud.app
   curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Accessing port 443 over http (not https) gives 200, can you check forwarding rules of ALB and see if the protocol is `htttps`?

```
$ curl -I http://www.darkcloud.app
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Thu, 09 Aug 2018 17:58:22 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: If "www.darkcloud.app" is the URL, then `openssl s_client -connect www.darkcloud.app:443` shows the following:
CONNECTED(00000003)
139674356164248:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794:
... basically, no SSL stuff is happening...

Comment: what should i do now ?

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly configured your Authoritative Name Servers to point to AWS. However, you have not configured any A records for your domain.

Check out the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating.html

Here is how I determined this:

Querying Googles DNS to see what NS records are configured for that domain:

```
 ttucker@dib:~$ dig ns darkcloud.app @8.8.8.8

 ; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> ns darkcloud.app @8.8.8.8
 ;; global options: +cmd
 ;; Got answer:
 ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 11295
 ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

 ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
 ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
 ;; QUESTION SECTION:
 ;darkcloud.app.                    IN      NS

 ;; ANSWER SECTION:
 darkcloud.app.             21592   IN      NS      ns-1351.awsdns-40.org.
 darkcloud.app.             21592   IN      NS      ns-1770.awsdns-29.co.uk.
 darkcloud.app.             21592   IN      NS      ns-442.awsdns-55.com.
 darkcloud.app.             21592   IN      NS      ns-532.awsdns-02.net.

 ;; Query time: 7 msec
 ;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
 ;; WHEN: Thu Aug 09 17:50:50 UTC 2018
 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 182
```

Then when I query each of the NS servers they indicate that there are no A records specified for your domain:

First:

```
ttucker@dib:~$ dig darkcloud.app @ns-1351.awsdns-40.org

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> darkcloud.app @ns-1351.awsdns-40.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34844
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;darkcloud.app.                     IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
darkcloud.app.              900     IN      SOA     ns-1351.awsdns-40.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; Query time: 6 msec
;; SERVER: 205.251.197.71#53(205.251.197.71)
;; WHEN: Thu Aug 09 17:52:37 UTC 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 127
```

Second:

```
ttucker@dib:~$ dig darkcloud.app @ns-1770.awsdns-29.co.uk 

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> darkcloud.app @ns-1770.awsdns-29.co.uk
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 38995
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;darkcloud.app.                     IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
darkcloud.app.              900     IN      SOA     ns-1351.awsdns-40.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; Query time: 19 msec
;; SERVER: 205.251.198.234#53(205.251.198.234)
;; WHEN: Thu Aug 09 17:53:09 UTC 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 127
```

Third:

```
ttucker@dib:~$ dig darkcloud.app @ns-442.awsdns-55.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> darkcloud.app @ns-442.awsdns-55.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17064
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;darkcloud.app.                     IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
darkcloud.app.              900     IN      SOA     ns-1351.awsdns-40.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; Query time: 6 msec
;; SERVER: 205.251.193.186#53(205.251.193.186)
;; WHEN: Thu Aug 09 17:53:50 UTC 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 127
```

Fourth:

```
ttucker@dib:~$ dig darkcloud.app @ns-532.awsdns-02.net

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> darkcloud.app @ns-532.awsdns-02.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49245
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;darkcloud.app.                     IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
darkcloud.app.              900     IN      SOA     ns-1351.awsdns-40.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 205.251.194.20#53(205.251.194.20)
;; WHEN: Thu Aug 09 17:54:30 UTC 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 127
```

Comment: I have created A record